# Is it possible to import types from module declaration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

For example, if I have a module declaration:

```
declare module 'redux-form' {
  declare type FormConfig = {
    form: string,
    validate?: Function
  };
}
```

Is it possible to somehow use this type in my code?

And if not, what are the ways to share types between several files?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to do `import type {FormConfig} from 'redux-form';`